# Custom Debug implementation for BTreeMap

Tags: rust, formatter

I have the following data structure:

```rust
struct Foo {
    a: BTreeMap<i32, i32>,
    b: BTreeMap<i32, i32>,
}
```

When I print it to stdout I'd like to show the `a` field in increasing direction and the `b` field in decreasing direction.

I can't really see how to do it from the `Display` documentation. Perhaps the [debug_map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.debug_map) helper would be useful? But I can't understand how to use it from after reading the example.

I've got as far as this but can't see how to compose it with some custom stuff like `"a: \n"` and `"b: \n"`.

```rust
impl fmt::Debug for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.debug_map()
            .entries(self.a.iter().map(|(k, v)| (k, v)))
            .entries(self.b.iter().rev().map(|(k, v)| (k, v)))
            .finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a9f5aeeb40d4c5e18fe39acf09a50334). Can you provide sample input and the desired output?

Comment: I think I get it now, I can just pepper it with `write!`s to get the output pretty the way I want. e.g. `write!("a: ");` and then the `debug_map` and then another `write!("\nb: ")` and then the `debug_map` for the other field etc. (I assume this is the most idiomatic way)

Comment: I have a follow up question: Can I use the `debug_map` helper to introduce brackets to each k-v pair I print? i.e. `[1, 2], ` instead of `1: 2, `?

Comment: You can use `debug_list` instead but it won't put them on the same line when pretty-printing

Answer (score 3):

I would use a wrapper struct for the reversed order, and then just use `debug_struct` instead:

```rust
impl fmt::Debug for Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        struct BTreeMapReversed<'a>(&'a BTreeMap<i32, i32>);
        impl fmt::Debug for BTreeMapReversed<'_> {
            fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
                f.debug_map()
                    .entries(self.0.iter().rev())
                    .finish()
            }
        }
    
        f.debug_struct("Foo")
            .field("a", &self.a)
            .field("b", &BTreeMapReversed(&self.b))
            .finish()
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:33] foo = Foo {
    a: {
        1: 2,
        3: 4,
    },
    b: {
        7: 8,
        5: 6,
    },
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f9ff53b9583f100c6ce8290ce0ea1d07)